# How do I order by year instead of by day?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to order by year on sqlite, but if I do the following:

```
select naam, achternaam, geboortedatum
from persoon
order by geboortedatum
```

then I get the following output:

```
Piet Jurring         06-03-1992
Linda Platvoet       10-11-2001
Jan Jenting          14-03-1988
Lisa Petersen        17-05-2000
Annemijn Van groenen 24-07-1998
Henk Geritssen       28-01-1993
```

How do I order by the year instead of day?

Comment: Change the format of your dates to YYYY-MM-DD and your code will work fine.

Comment: But isn't is possible to sort by year in this format?

Comment: By year only? This means that the dates of each year, say 1988 will be arbitrary ordered.

Comment: If it's SQLite database and `geboortedatum` is stored in a `dd-MM-yyyy` format, you have convert that "date" into proper ISO format (`yyyy-MM-dd`).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your data model!  Don't store dates as strings.  If you do, use YYYY-MM-DD.

In any case, you can order by the last four characters using:

```
order by substr(geboortedatum, -4)
```

Comment: In SQLite dates are stored as strings.

Comment: @LarsBerger if you have more than 1 rows for a year they will not be ordered correctly because you order only by year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -
if `geboortedatum` is date then-
`order by CAST(strftime('%Y',geboortedatum) as decimal);`
else if its a string -
`order by CAST(strftime('%Y',date(geboortedatum)) as decimal)`

Pls note you need to convert to decimal/integer so order by works perfectly.

Comment: `strftime()` and date() return NULL if the date string is not in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: in such case you can use substr `order by cast(substr (geboortedatum,6) as decimal)`